# How to find previous td element using jquery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table like this

```
<table>
    <tr><td id="space_bet1" height="10"></td></tr>
    <tr><td id="unscr1">Today</td></tr>
    <tr><td id="space_bet2" height="10"></td></tr>
    <tr><td id="unscr2">Tomorrow</td></tr>
    <tr><td id="space_bet3" height="10"></td></tr>
    <tr><td id="unscr3">Yesterday</td></tr>
    <tr><td id="space_bet4" height="10"></td></tr>
    <tr><td id="unscr4">next week</td></tr>
    <tr><td id="space_bet5" height="10"></td></tr>
    <tr><td id="unscr5">next month</td></tr>
    <tr><td id="space_bet6" height="10"></td></tr>
</table>
```

I want find the td before space_bet3, I tried prev() method but it don't work anyway

```
alert($("#space_bet3").prev().prev().attr("id"))  // undefined error
alert($("#space_bet3").prev("#space_bet2").attr("id"))  // undefined error
```

what is my wrong to do that? how can find id before of space_bet3, Thank you

Comment: `prev` only looks at sibling elements. Your "previous" `td` is actually under another parent (tr), so you have to go up the DOM tree then down again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As there is no sibling(`<td>`) before the element `#space_bet3`, `prev()` on it will return empty set.

1. Get the `<tr>` ancestor
2. Get previous `<tr>` sibling
3. Get the children `<td>`
4. Get the `id` attribute value.

**code:**

```
$('#space_bet3')
    .closest('tr') // Get first ancestor `<tr>` element
    .prev() // Get previous element
    .children('td') // Get direct descendant `<td>` element
    .attr('id'); // Get `id` of the element
```

```js
var id = $('#space_bet3')
  .closest('tr') // Get first ancestor `<tr>` element
  .prev() // Get previous element
  .children('td') // Get direct descendant `<td>` element
  .attr('id'); // Get `id` of the element

console.log(id);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="space_bet1" height="10"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="unscr1">Today</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="space_bet2" height="10"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="unscr2">Tomorrow</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="space_bet3" height="10"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="unscr3">Yesterday</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="space_bet4" height="10"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="unscr4">next week</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="space_bet5" height="10"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="unscr5">next month</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="space_bet6" height="10"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try these :-

```
$('#space_bet3').parent('tr').prev().find('td').attr("id");
```

It may help you.